# Count rows that have the same relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables. Palette, color and a relationship table palette_color. Just like this sample:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe832/2

I would like to count the palettes that has the same exact colors in the relationship table. I am already doing it as you can see in the example. But I believe my method is not efficient. It takes almost 2 seconds to run.

I am using SQL Server.

This is where I count the rows:

```
(
SELECT count(DISTINCT palette_id) as total FROM palette_color COLOR
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (( (SELECT color_id FROM palette_color WHERE palette_id = PALETTE.id) EXCEPT (SELECT color_id FROM palette_color WHERE palette_id = COLOR.palette_id) )
        UNION ALL
        ( (SELECT color_id FROM palette_color WHERE palette_id = COLOR.palette_id) EXCEPT (SELECT color_id FROM palette_color WHERE palette_id = PALETTE.id) ))
 ) as total
```

And in the where clause, I make sure only the first palette appear on the result

```
WHERE  id =
(
    SELECT MIN(palette_id) FROM palette_color COLOR
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (( (SELECT color_id FROM palette_color WHERE palette_id = PALETTE.id) EXCEPT (SELECT color_id FROM palette_color WHERE palette_id = COLOR.palette_id) )
            UNION ALL
            ( (SELECT color_id FROM palette_color WHERE palette_id = COLOR.palette_id) EXCEPT (SELECT color_id FROM palette_color WHERE palette_id = PALETTE.id) ))
)
```

Comment: Hello. Your example is great, but can you explain. `count palettes has same exact colors`? because your result show `palette_id` and a `count(*)`. My guess is you choose a random `palette_id` and there is a total of `count(*)`. other different `palette_id` with same colors?

Comment: If you really only have 5 colors, then here is a fast solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe832/30 - won't work for more than ~30 colors though.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, can you post that as answer with explanation?

Comment: sorry, there will be much more.

Comment: @FelixPamittan This is a great solution. He just asign a `bit` to each `color_id` and create an unique `integer` for each palette. Similar idea as mine creating a string with `color_id`. But as he explain you can only have 32 / 64  bits in an integer. So only work with 32 / 64 colors.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, yup I understood it. I just think it qualifies as another answer so that more users will learn about it. Plus, comments can be obsolete, so Blogbear's comment might be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I create a string list of all the `color_id` in a `palete_id` using `FOR XML PATH`

Then group by and count each group of colors.

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe832/39) (12ms)

```
with cList as (
    SELECT  p.id palette_id, 
            STUFF(( SELECT ',' + CAST(pc.color_id as varchar(10) )
                    FROM palette_color pc
                    WHERE pc.palette_id = p.id
                    ORDER BY pc.color_id
                  FOR
                    XML PATH('')
                  ), 1, 1, '') AS ColorList
    FROM palette p
)
select min(palette_id) palette_id, ColorList, count(*) Total
from cList
group by ColorList
```

Comment: Great idea! You can replace `ColorList` with `min(palette_id)` to get the `palette_id`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan Thanks, I was going to do a complicated join to bring back the palette_id (doh!!)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the FOR XML PATH:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT MIN(palette_id), count(*), colors
FROM (
SELECT id as palette_id,
colors = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + convert(nvarchar(20), pc.color_id)
          FROM palette_color pc
          WHERE pc.palette_id = palette.id
          ORDER BY pc.color_id
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM palette) a
GROUP BY colors
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe832/33/0)**:

```
|    |    |    colors |
|----|----|-----------|
|  1 | 15 |       1,2 |
|  6 | 60 |     1,2,3 |
| 26 |  6 |   1,2,3,4 |
| 46 | 42 | 1,2,3,4,5 |
| 28 | 18 |     1,3,4 |
| 34 | 36 |   1,3,4,5 |
```

As a bonus, this solution gives you the actual colors used in the palette